# high frequency timing .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I'm looking to create a high frequency callback thread.  Essentially I need a function to execute at a regular high frequency (up to 100Hz) interval. I realize that windows has a normal thread execution slice is ~15ms.  I would like to specify a regular interval that can be faster than 15ms.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have an external device that needs to be messaged at a certain interval.  The interval is variable depending on the situation.  I expect that I would not ever need more than a 100Hz (10ms) message rate.

I can of course implement a spin loop, however, I was hoping there is a solution that would not require so much wasted resources.

The provided links to questions/answers do not resolve this question.  While I agree that the question has been asked several different ways,  there has not been a good solution that actually solved the problem.

Most of the answers provided talk to using Stopwatch and performing the timing task manually which is entirely too CPU intensive.  The only viable solutions were using the multimedia timers which had a couple pitfalls as Haans mentioned.  I have found another solution however that I'll add below.  I do not know of the pitfalls at this time but I plan to do some testing and research.  I am still interested in comments regarding the solution.

---

WINAPI call via

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateTimerQueueTimer(
  _Out_     PHANDLE phNewTimer,
  _In_opt_  HANDLE TimerQueue,
  _In_      WAITORTIMERCALLBACK Callback,
  _In_opt_  PVOID Parameter,
  _In_      DWORD DueTime,
  _In_      DWORD Period,
  _In_      ULONG Flags
);
```

and

```
BOOL WINAPI DeleteTimerQueueTimer(
  _In_opt_  HANDLE TimerQueue,
  _In_      HANDLE Timer,
  _In_opt_  HANDLE CompletionEvent
);
```

Link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
I'm using PInvoke to accomplish this.  This would also be required when dealing with the multimedia timers as well however.

My PInvoke signature for those interested.
[Pinvoke link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateTimerQueueTimer)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool CreateTimerQueueTimer(out IntPtr phNewTimer,
   IntPtr TimerQueue, WaitOrTimerDelegate Callback, IntPtr Parameter,
   uint DueTime, uint Period, uint Flags);

// This is the callback delegate to use.
public delegate void WaitOrTimerDelegate (IntPtr lpParameter, bool TimerOrWaitFired);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool DeleteTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr TimerQueue, IntPtr Timer,
   IntPtr CompletionEvent);
```

use CreateTimerQueueTimer to start a timer callback.  Use DeleteTimerQueueTimer to stop the timer callback.  This is somewhat flexible as you can create custom queues as well.  However, the easiest implementation if only a single instance is needed would be to use the default queue.

I tested this solution along side one using the Stopwatch with a spin loop and the results I received in regards to timing were nearly identical. However, the CPU Load was significantly different on my machine.

Stopwatch with spin loop - ~12-15% constant CPU load (About 50% of one of my cores)
CreateTimerQueueTimer - ~3-4% constant CPU load

I also feel the code maintenance will be reduced using the CreateTimerQueueTimer option. as it doesn't require logic to be added to your code flow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a *lot* of inaccurate information spread through the links and comments.  Yes, by default the clock tick interrupt is 1/64 seconds = 15.625 msec on most machines but it can be changed.  Also the reason that some machines appear to operate on another rate.  The Windows multi-media api, available from winmm.dll lets you tinker with it.

What you *don't* want to do is using a Stopwatch.  You'll only get an accurate interval measurement out of it when you use it in a hot loop that constantly check if the interval has passed.  Windows treats such a thread unkindly when its quantum expires, the thread won't be re-scheduled to run for a while when other threads compete for the processor.  This effect is easy to miss since you don't typically debug your code with other processes actively running and burning cpu time.

The function you want to use is timeSetEvent(), it provides a highly accurate timer that can go as low as 1 millisecond.  It is self-correcting, reducing the interval if necessary (and possible) to catch up when the previous callback got delayed due to scheduling constraints.  Beware however that it is difficult to use, the callback is made from a threadpool thread, similar to System.Threading.Timer, so be sure to use safe interlocking and take countermeasures that ensure that you won't get trouble from re-entrancy.

A completely different approach is timeBeginPeriod(), it alters the clock interrupt rate.  That has many side-effects, for one Thread.Sleep() becomes more accurate.  Which tends to be the easier solution since you can make that synchronous.  Just sleep for 1 msec and you'll get the interrupt rate.  Some code to play with that demonstrates the way it works:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        timeBeginPeriod(10);
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int ix = 0; ix < 100; ++ix) Thread.Sleep(1);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} msec", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        timeEndPeriod(10);
    }

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern uint timeBeginPeriod(int msec);
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern uint timeEndPeriod(int msec);
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
1001 msec
995 msec
999 msec
999 msec
999 msec
991 msec
999 msec
999 msec
999 msec
999 msec
999 msec
990 msec
999 msec
998 msec
...
```

Do beware however of a problem with this approach, if another process on your machine has already lowered the clock interrupt rate below 10 msec then you will not get a second out of this code.  That's very awkward to deal with, you can only make it truly safe by asking for a 1 msec rate and sleeping for 10.  Don't run that on a battery operated machine.  Do favor timeSetEvent().

Comment: Thanks Hans, I can always appreciate your responses and advice.  I actually found something that solves my problem while researching the API you mention.  That is using the CreateTimerQueueTimer.  This appears to give me the resolution with the API you mention but without the drawback regarding competition of changing the timing events.  Another added benefit is that it is from the kernal32.dll.  Any thoughts regarding the CreateTimerQueueTimer API class?

Comment: Yeah, it is the recommended alternative for timeSetEvent().  I don't know enough about its ability to alter the clock interrupt rate, you'll have to experiment.

Comment: Seeing as how no more answers can be provided.  I'm marking this as the answer.  It provides a solution that would work for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), which uses the same hi-performance timers used by DirectX.

Comment: When available. Don't forget to check [IsHighResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx)

Comment: This should be true on most modern hardware I presume.

Comment: Yes it should but you would still need to check it, just in case.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps.  I need a particular callback to occur at an interval < 15ms.  The stopwatch can give me precise timing, however, I would have to burn CPU in a loop constantly checking the time in order to achieve the objective which is what I'm trying to avoid (the burning of the CPU).

Comment: @galford: You really should say in your question *title* that you want a precisely scheduled callback, and not just precise timer measurement ("timing" can mean either one)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Indeed I will update the question.  I suppose I assumed it to be obvious with the thread time slice explanation along with the high frequency message interval requirement.

Comment: @galford13x: while StopWatch doesn't have a callback built-in, you can still try to check it in a loop, you might be able to get sub-millisecond timing.  I can come up with some code if you want.  Either way, using a non-deterministic, GC language like C# is not the best approach here for doing near real-time programming.  A better approach would be to write this portion in C/C++.

Comment: @Ali B:  I already have a solution you mention using a spin loop.  The problem as I talked about earlier is the CPU resources it requires.  How would writing this portion in C/C++ help?  I can always write the code in C# using unmanned objects to stop GC on that portion or even stop GC on any objects accessed by the thread it's running on via C#.  I don't need strict real time operation.  If one execution happens 2 msec late, but the next is 2msec early then my goal will be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Note that part of the reason why 15ms is the effective minimum `Sleep` time is that it can take that order of magnitude to actually swap your process out, swap another one in, let it have some time to do anything, swap it out and swap yours in again. Assuming you have multiple cores, dedicating one to handingly your 100Hz updater is probably best, especially if you know when you'd like to skip a few cycles for a manually generated garbage collection, and/or use C/C++ as suggested.

Comment: Not to mention swapping context happens at a specific minimum frequency which is different from client to server versions of Windows.  See Windows quantum

Comment: The reason the 15ms plays a part is like Haans mentioned, that is minimum time slice given to a thread by windows.  Of course like he said this is platform and OS version dependent.  You can test this by writing a multithreaded application that records time and uses the Thread.Sleep(2) for a few seconds then print out all the times recorded in the thread.  You'll notice they are ~15.6ms apart.  Of course a thread can use less than 15ms simply by calling Thread.Sleep(0) giving up the rest of his slice to something more important.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Sleep()` does not seem to be as inaccurate as you may think at such small intervals, The following on Windows 8.1 x64 i7 Laptop .NET 4.0:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace HighFrequency
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var count = 0;
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            while(count <= 1000)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                count++;
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("C# .NET 4.0 avg. {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / count);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> C# .NET 4.0 avg. 0.00197391928071928

So just under 2ms interval! I guess if there was more contention that could rise pretty quickly, though I do have a number of apps open, just nothing grinding away.

At sleeping for 10ms i.e. 100HZ, got an average of 0.0109... pretty much spot on!

Comment: Unless something has changed in Win8 for the sleep call, then in general sleep is not a good mechanism to keep time.  Also, sleep can be unpredictable in it's minimum timing when the high frequency timer is changed on the system.  Bottom line, while you're getting ~10ms, when I run this on my Win7 machine i'm getting 15.6ms on avg.  Also I wasn't looking for avg values, I was looking for precise consistent timing, so 12ms, 9ms, 11ms, 8ms would not be acceptable.

Comment: True, I would not use it to keep time, just for high frequency loops - I would measure the actual elapsed time using a `Stopwatch` - but still not an option if you want consistent time.