# Looking for millisecond precision logging in windows application

Tags: c#, windows, logging

Recently i am looking for a solution for my windows application, which was causing improper logging behind file..
I found come to know issue in resolution time of windows dateime.now 
So, I am trying to avoid that. i created sample application based on possible hint given in the forms answers....

Here`s the sample code and its output....

```
private Timer tmr = new Timer();
private Stopwatch ss;

void tmr_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
     WriteData();
}

private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
     ss = new Stopwatch();
     ss.Start();
     tmr.Interval = 1;
     tmr.Tick += new EventHandler( tmr_Tick );
     tmr.Start();
     WriteData();
}
void WriteData()
{
     Console.WriteLine(ss.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

OutPut:
0
19
29
49
69
79
99
109
122
142
162
172
192
202
222
232
252
282
272
294
314
334
341

How can i get more accuracy in this code....????

Comment: @I4V - That article is somewhat out of date in that Stopwatch does the same thing, i.e. it is the result of integrating that 'HiResTimer' into the framework post 2.0.

Comment: @I4V Yes like jamesmus says, that article is woefully out of date now. You would just use Stopwatch.

Answer (score 3):

```
 tmr.Interval = 1;
```

That's a small number, some virtue in not being able to make it smaller.  But no, you are not going to get a timer to tick a thousand times per second.  There are three factors that determine the actual rate at which the Timer fires the Tick event:

- how busy your UI thread is doing other things.  Like running a Click event handler or painting the window.  The Tick event handler can only run when the UI thread isn't busy with anything, it must be *idle*.  This is of course a highly variable number, a matters a great deal what the user of your app is doing.  Some things he can do are pretty expensive, like resizing the window of your app.  Typical UI thread duties, like painting, take a handful of milliseconds.  Quick enough for the human eye, but quite noticeable if you require that Tick event to run so frequently.  It just isn't going to run, could be hundreds of milliseconds if your UI is convoluted.  You'll need a different kind of Timer class to avoid this, either System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer.  They are timer classes that run their code on a thread-pool thread.  With the advantage that it won't be delayed by what's going on in the UI thread.  And the significant disadvantage that you have to be very careful what you do in that code, you certainly can't update the UI.
- how busy the machine is doing other things.  Like executing the thread of another process or device driver.  This is a primary task of the operating system, allowing hundreds of threads to share the processor.  The thread scheduler in Windows determines when a thread gets a chance to run.  Once it gains the processor and executes, it is allowed to run for a while, a period called the *quantum*.  A typical quantum is 45 milliseconds for a thread owned by a window in the foreground.  Other threads are *suspended* until they get a chance to run.  This of course spells doom to your plan to run a Tick event a thousand times per second.  You'll need to carefully control what other programs run on the machine, a many-core processor will help a great deal.
- how often Windows updates a timer.  The core operating system feature that's involved with that is the clock interrupt.  Used for many things, it is the basic heartbeat of the operating system.  The normal state of the processor is to not be doing anything, it is turned off.  The clock tick interrupt wakes it up from the halt state and the operating system checks if any work needs to be performed.  The default interrupt rate is 64 times per second, once every 15.625 millisecond.  This will also affect the timer's accuracy, nothing can happen when the processor is halted.  So by design, you will never get a 1 msec rate, it can never be less than 16 msec.

The latter bullet is certainly the biggest hangup.  You can in fact *change* the interrupt rate in your program, it requires a pinvoke call to the timeBeginPeriod() winapi function.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632882/17034) shows how.  Also mentions the timeSetEvent() function, the one you'd need to get anywhere close to a timer that has a reasonable guarantee of being able to sustain a 1 millisecond rate.

Comment: I've upvoted you because that's a nice detailed description of some of the timer mechanics.  I interpreted the original question to be about the resolution of Stopwatch with the Timer simply used as an exploratory (i.e. throw away) mechanism to check that.  Re-reading, though, it's not actually clear!

Answer (score 2):

Stopwatch uses the Windows Performance Counter APIs under the covers so it should be pretty accurate (the Performance Counter APIs are quoted as having a resolution in the low microsecond range).

Your test is invalid, though, because you are actually measuring the drift in the Timer rather than any inaccuracy in the Stopwatch.

On the subject of the Timer - it looks like you are using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer class in your sample.  That's not a great choice for accuracy; it's sole advantage is that it raises the Tick event on the UI thread.  Try the System.Threading.Timer class instead - you may find it gives you results closer to what you expect (although still suffers from some drift).

```
var timerCallback = (TimerCallback)(sw => Console.WriteLine(((Stopwatch)sw).Elapsed));
var timerInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var timer = new Timer(timerCallback, stopwatch, timerInterval, timerInterval);
```

Ultimately it's pretty difficult to test the accuracy of the Stopwatch because there isn't anything else readily available that is more accurate!