# c# moving rectangles vs moving panels on timer.tick (as speed)

Tags: c#, user-interface, timer, drag-and-drop, drawing

I have a timer. When it ticks , by calculating based on formulas, the position of 12 panels changes.

The problem is, although timer's interval is 1 milisecond, the moves are very slow.There are many calculations. What can be done for improving speed, using drawing class or something else?

The gui shows positions, I can move the panels by clicking, so the values. If the correct way is drawing class, do I have a chance to move the rectangles by clicking and take the values of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> although timer's interval is 1 milisecond

That's the core problem, a Timer cannot tick that fast.  Actual timer resolution is constrained by the operating system's clock interrupt rate.  Which ticks 64 times per second on most Windows machines.  Or once every 15.625 millsecond.  The smallest interval you can hope to get is therefore 16 msec.  So these panels probably now move 16 times slower than you hoped they would.

Keep in mind how this is observed, you only need to keep human eyes happy.  They can't perceive anything that changes at 1 msec, anything that updates faster than 25 times per second just looks like a blur.  Something that's taken advantage of in TV and the cinema, a movie updates at 24 frames per second.  Once ever 42 milliseconds.

So a sane setting for the Timer.Interval is a hair below three times the clock interrupt rate, 46 milliseconds.  The actual tick interval will be 3 x 15.625 = 46.875 msec on a regular machine.  And still close to 46 msec if the machine runs with a higher clock interrupt rate.  You'll get an equivalent frame rate of 21 fps.  Right on the edge of a blur to human eyes.  The next lower sane rate is two times the interrupt rate or 31 msec for 32 fps.  Making it any smaller doesn't make sense, it isn't observable and just burns cpu time for no benefit.

And, important, the rate at which the panel moves is now determined by how much you change its Location property in the Tick event handler.  The interval is fixed so the amount of motion you get is determined by the increment in the position.  Which will **not** be one pixel, probably what you are using now.

Comment: I wanted an answer, you wrote an article, thank you very much for this information and take your time:) Actually I am on generating pulses for a robot that is constructed on 6 motors working synchronous, and with a simple language manage them. So the fps seems enough for human eyes on visualising the motions but i would want to know the pulses are generated exactly 10,5 or 1 miliseconds for these motors, so I could know their position. Again, thank you Hans.

Comment: That question would have a completely different answer.  I already [wrote one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632882/17034)