# .net thread.sleep inaccurate

Tags: .net, multithreading, sleep

I am getting crazy !!. 
I am sending audio over gsm and by voice specifications, I must send voice date packets then wait for 20 milliseconds to get normal voice. I use system.threading.thread.sleep(20). However, I noticed that sound is slow .But when i run another different application , sound gets normal.

After some debugging, i found that system.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20) takes 31 milliseconds , but if I run another different application, the Thread.Sleep (20) will always be accurate.

what are the other alternatives that I can use in order to make the thread sleep for 20 Milli-seconds accurately & at the same time does not impact PC performance.

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to get that accurate you will have to spinwait which is bad for PC performance.

Comment: Sleep accuracy is determined by the clock interrupt rate, by default it ticks 64 times per second.  Once every 15.625 msec.  So a Sleep(20) cannot complete until two ticks have passed, 2 x 15.625 = 31.25 msec.  The interrupt rate can be changed, a browser or media player is apt to do so.  They call [timeBeginPeriod()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632882/17034), so can you.

Comment: Note that upping the clock interrupt rate can have a significant affect on battery life if that is of any concern.  http://wp.me/p1fTCO-kJ

Comment: Dear Hans , your calculations are correct. What i get is 31 msec & after a while is 32 msec then 31 msec too. when i open firefox , it gets accurate to 20 msec for 500 readings.  Question now to to recover this issue.. Shall I set timebeginPeriod to what ?

Comment: Hans ... you did it .. Thanks so much :) . it works like magic. I used   timeBeginPeriod(10) ,and everything works fined . Please advice how to set your post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, accurate timings generally need a thread/process that is not going to time sliced out, to do this, you must `Spin` rather than `Sleep`.

**Option 1**

If you want absolute accuracy over anything else, I would use a dedicated high priority thread with a Stopwatch.

```
bool running = true;
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (running)
    {
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 20)
        {
            RunCode();
            sw.Restart();
        }
    }
}) { Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest, IsBackground = true };

t.Start();

// ...

running = false;
t.Join();
```

**Option 2**

Bit more slimmed down, doesn't run on a different thread but still spins.

```
while (true) 
{
    SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20));
    RunCode();
}
```

**Option 3**

Some open source high resolution timer code. e.g. https://gist.github.com/HakanL/4669495

Comment: I have tried the first option and the second, but it seems that I make something wrong. The stopwatch does not give accurate data. I found the clock interruption change a sample solution.  Thanks so much for your great support. really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it's quite possible that 1 & 2 don't work straight out the box - I didn't test them, should have added that :)  No problems.

Comment: Dear James,  Thanks so much for your great support. really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`Sleep(20)` means sleep for at least 20 ms. Basically, it suspends the thread and doesn't resume scheduling for the specified delay. After that the thread still has to be scheduled to actually resume running. Depending on what other threads are running that could be immediately or some time later. There are no guarantees here.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) calls this out:

> The system clock ticks at a specific rate called the clock resolution.
>   **The actual timeout might not be exactly the specified timeout**, because
>   the specified timeout will be adjusted to coincide with clock ticks.
>   For more information on clock resolution and the waiting time, see the
>   Sleep function topic. This method calls the Sleep function from the
>   Windows system APIs.

Comment: So , what do you recommend to use ?.
I see a program in Java, it use Thread.Sleep (20) & seems to work pretty well. is this related to the programming language, or the OS ?.
& for .net , what is the best solution for me  with good balance between time accuracy & CPU utilization.

Thanks.

Comment: I would expect the same behavior for a Java application - at least on Windows. In fact, the Java docs has the same note about the timeout. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: I have still one issue, when i use the winmme timeBegion  , it works like charm in x 32 bits system. but on x 64 bits systems, it gives strange behavoir. Kindly advice how to overcome this on 64 systems.